# How to check if a number is already in the first column of a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to vstack an array A1 with an array A2 if the first number of the array A2 is not in the first column of the array A1:

```
A1 = np.array([])
numbers = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for number in numbers:
   if number not in A1[:,0]:
      A2 = [number,10]
      A1 = np.vstack((A1,A2))
```

But of course at the beggining A1 is not a 2D array, so A1[:,0] will produce an `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

At the moment I create a dummy empty 2D array and then I supress the dummy values:

```
A1 = np.zeros(shape=(2,2))
numbers = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for number in numbers:
   if number not in A1[:,0]:
      A2 = [number, 10]
      A1 = np.vstack((A1,A2))
A1 = A1[2:,:]
```

But, ok... we all agree that it's disgusting to do that...

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It is inefficient and generally not a good idea to operate on `numpy` arrays as if they were lists.

Instead, use the vectorised functionality available to `numpy`. Below is an example.

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]

unique = np.unique(numbers)
constant = np.ones(len(unique)) * 10

A1 = np.vstack((unique, constant)).T
```

If order is important, use this instead:

```
idx = np.unique(numbers, return_index=True)[1]
unique = numbers[sorted(idx)]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `np.unique` also sorts the array. If the input numbers are not sorted, you will get a different output.

Comment: Damn, my example was too simple, because in my case I also need to maximize the value of the second number in A2 which is not always 10. I will edit my question.

Comment: @obchardon, even in this case, use `numpy `:)

Comment: @jpp you could just do `unique = number[sorted(idx)]` instead of a list comprehension